# How are non-folder files called?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming, file-handling, file-systems

Maybe it looks like a weird question, but what term should be attributed inside the code for files that are not folders to differentiate them from folders?

If I need write 2 functions isFolder() and isFile() 2nd one has a misleading name because folders are files too

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: *has a misleading name* are you sure? Most libraries in any language have separate is_directory/is_file functions and they behave as expected (i.e. is_file returns false for directories)

Comment: On Unix & POSIX, folders don't exist. But directories are indeed files.

Comment: Note that if you're targeting Windows, "isFolder" may be a technically incorrect name. Under Windows terminology, "folder" is a user interface object that may or may not relate to a directory, while "directory" is specifically a structure on a disk or similar media. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110216-00/?p=11473 for more info.

Comment: “Files” and “folders/directories” are both _file system objects_, and probably the most common ones, but there are others, like symbolic links. But folders/directories are definitely not files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends upon the [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) and the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system).

In POSIX and Unix, a file can be a directory, a **plain file**, a block device, a character device, a FIFO, a socket, a symbolic link, ... See [POSIX stat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) & Linux [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), notice that file can have different *types*.

So if you want to speak of a file whose type is plain and which is a sequence of bytes, you say that is is a *plain file* or a *regular file*.

If you want any file which is not a directory you could speak of a "non-directory" file (or maybe non-directory [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)); it could be a plain file, a socket, a fifo, a symlink, etc...

Notice that *POSIX and Linux don't know about folders* (except on the desktop). They speak of [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_%28computing%29).

Notice also that files are quite different on Windows, on MacOSX, on Linux, on POSIX....

Some experimental OSes don't even have files. They are persisting data in some other way. Historically, the very first editions of [MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) (or of [MVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVS)) did not had any directories (or folders).

Answer (score 6):

This depends heavily on the filesystem and the operating system. For example, on Unix, there are no folders at all:[image: Unix Filesystem Objects Hierarchy]

Windows has completely different terminology. Classic MacOS had a different terminology, which, in OSX, is now mixing with Unix terminology.